# Is there a way to render PDF in FreePascal or Delphi via AggPas?

Tags: delphi, pdf, freepascal

Is there a way or method to use AggPass to render an existing PDF file?

For example, I have a PDF file. Can I use AggPass to render this PDF using FreePascal or Delphi?

Comment: If you meant `AggPas`, the Anti-Grain Geometry library wrapper, then only in a way, that you'd make a preview of your PDF file with another library and render this preview by AGG. AGG itself doesn't support PDF files, since it's (just) a rendering library.

Comment: That clarifies things alot. What would you recommend to render PDF via FreePascal or Delphi, such that the text inside it and images are editable?

Comment: rendering doesn't imply _editable_, just _printable_. You're mixing concepts.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelphi%5D%5Bpdf%5D+display  and  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelphi%5D%5Bpdf%5D+create  and
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelphi%5D%5Bpdf%5D+edit

Comment: I get the idea... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AggPas is not capable of reading PDF files.